# Writing multiple documents to Solr shards via Solrj

Tags: solr, sharding, solrj

I am currently storing a collection of documents to one Solr server via [SolrServer.add(Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs)](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html#add%28java.util.Collection%29). I want to shard the server into e.g. shards. Is it possible to use this Collection-adding method and picking the correct shard based on each single document in this collection?

My simple sharding strategy is to pick the correct shard, by using the hashCode/modulo method like described in http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch.

```
uniqueId.hashCode() % numServers
```

**Update**

OK, I have found a distributed update processor in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2355, but maybe there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I ended up with a mapping I stored in the database regarding the data entities I use. So I map entity to Solr instances.